# Gravar um Json string no banco de dados c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estou conseguindo receber os dados corretamente, e os conseguindo separar corretamente também, único problema é que não sei como usar os valores e poder gravar no banco de dados, poderiam me ajudar ?

A imagem abaixo mostra como estou recebendo os dados e os tratando até então:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SellAdd(string products)
    {
        var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(products);
        string[] model = objects.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();


        foreach (var product in model)
        {

        //    var produtoCodigo = await _productManager.GetProductCodigoAsync();

          /*  var venda = new ApplicationSell
            {
                Quantidade = product.quantidadeProduto,
                Total = product.valorTotalProduto,
                ProductId = produtoCodigo.Codigo
            };

            await _productManager.GravaVendaAsync(venda);  */
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Olá @Matheus. Evite colocar o seu código em imagens, ao invés edite a sua questão e coloque-o lá.

Comment: tem algum código onde esteja a gravar alguma coisa na base de dados? Ou ainda não tem nada relativo a isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, na minha humilde opinião, você poderia utilizar o entity framework para acesso ao banco de dados.

Criaria uma classe:

```
public class Products {
    int    codigoProduto {get;set;}
    int    quantidadeProduto {get;set;}
    double valorTotalProduto {get;set;}
}

Products  prod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(products);
```

Logo abaixo você poderia acessar as propriedades `prod.valorTotalProduto` por exemplo.

Em seguida usaria o entity framework para gravar ,atualizar ou deletar no banco de dados.

Espero ter ajudado me algo.

Comment: Mas no caso a class Products tem que ter exatamente o mesmo nome do json no caso ?

Comment: Sim, pois você está fazendo uma associação.